# Indexing is not as fast as expected for lookups in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

I have unique twitter words collection in my database. The document inside it has the following shape:

```
{
    _id: <some-object-id>,
    initial: "t",
    word: "the",
    count: 986,
    tweets: <position information for the given word>
}
```

I have tried the following codes to create indexes:

```
db.tweet_words.create_index([("word", pymongo.ASCENDING), ("initial", pymongo.ASCENDING)], background=True)
```

and

```
db.tweet_words.create_index("word", background=True)
```

and

```
db.tweet_words.create_index([("word", pymongo.HASHED)], background=True)
```

Although using these indexes helped the update command to be run faster, it still runs relatively slow. I am thinking that there should be better way.

Here is my update commands:

```py
from pymongo import UpdateOne
# connect to db stuff
# create indexing using one of the approaches above
commands = []
for word in words: # this is actually not the real loop I've used but it fits for this example
    # assume tweet_id's and position is calculated here
    initial = word[0]
    ret = {"tweet_id": tweet_id, "pos": (beg, end)} # additional information about word
    command = UpdateOne({"word": word, "initial": initial}, # use query {"word": word} only if one of bottom two indexing strategy is chosen
        {
            "$setOnInsert": {"initial": initial},
            "$inc": {"count": 1},
            "$push": {"tweets": ret},
        },
    commands.append(command)
    if len(commands) % 1000 == 0:
        db.tweet_words.bulk_write(commands, ordered=False)
        commands = []
```

You can find the real code [here](https://gist.github.com/talha252/f189c2b3ebaf6a140a4b0af5aa0980ae).

Here is the output of `pprint(db.tweet_words.find({"word": word}).explain())` (couldn't come up how to use explain method on `UpdateOne` or `bulk_write`) when there is ~130k documents present in the collection:

```
{'executionStats': {'allPlansExecution': [],
                    'executionStages': {'advanced': 1,
                                        'alreadyHasObj': 0,
                                        'docsExamined': 1,
                                        'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 0,
                                        'inputStage': {'advanced': 1,
                                                       'direction': 'forward',
                                                       'dupsDropped': 0,
                                                       'dupsTested': 0,
                                                       'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 0,
                                                       'indexBounds': {'initial': ['[MinKey, '
                                                                                   'MaxKey]'],
                                                                       'word': ['["seval", '
                                                                                '"seval"]']},
                                                       'indexName': 'word_1_initial_1',
                                                       'indexVersion': 2,
                                                       'invalidates': 0,
                                                       'isEOF': 1,
                                                       'isMultiKey': False,
                                                       'isPartial': False,
                                                       'isSparse': False,
                                                       'isUnique': False,
                                                       'keyPattern': {'initial': 1,
                                                                      'word': 1},
                                                       'keysExamined': 1,
                                                       'multiKeyPaths': {'initial': [],
                                                                         'word': []},
                                                       'nReturned': 1,
                                                       'needTime': 0,
                                                       'needYield': 0,
                                                       'restoreState': 0,
                                                       'saveState': 0,
                                                       'seeks': 1,
                                                       'seenInvalidated': 0,
                                                       'stage': 'IXSCAN',
                                                       'works': 2},
                                        'invalidates': 0,
                                        'isEOF': 1,
                                        'nReturned': 1,
                                        'needTime': 0,
                                        'needYield': 0,
                                        'restoreState': 0,
                                        'saveState': 0,
                                        'stage': 'FETCH',
                                        'works': 2},
                    'executionSuccess': True,
                    'executionTimeMillis': 0,
                    'nReturned': 1,
                    'totalDocsExamined': 1,
                    'totalKeysExamined': 1},
 'ok': 1.0,
 'queryPlanner': {'indexFilterSet': False,
                  'namespace': 'twitter.tweet_words',
                  'parsedQuery': {'word': {'$eq': 'seval'}},
                  'plannerVersion': 1,
                  'rejectedPlans': [],
                  'winningPlan': {'inputStage': {'direction': 'forward',
                                                 'indexBounds': {'initial': ['[MinKey, '
                                                                             'MaxKey]'],
                                                                 'word': ['["seval", '
                                                                          '"seval"]']},
                                                 'indexName': 'word_1_initial_1',
                                                 'indexVersion': 2,
                                                 'isMultiKey': False,
                                                 'isPartial': False,
                                                 'isSparse': False,
                                                 'isUnique': False,
                                                 'keyPattern': {'initial': 1,
                                                                'word': 1},
                                                 'multiKeyPaths': {'initial': [],
                                                                   'word': []},
                                                 'stage': 'IXSCAN'},
                                  'stage': 'FETCH'}},
 'serverInfo': {'gitVersion': 'f288a3bdf201007f3693c58e140056adf8b04839',
                'host': 'MostWanted',
                'port': 27017,
                'version': '4.0.4'}}
```

Is there a solvable bottleneck in my code? Or this is just as good as gets?

Comment: Where do you first assign `commands` to something in your code?

Comment: Updated the code. It is not the real code I've used in my project. That's why I mistakenly skip it.

Comment: Yeah... I don't see anything obvious so a little worried by it not being the real-code you may have oversimplified it - especially if you've just missed out a necessary line :)

Comment: Anyway - get it to explain the query being executed and make sure it's deciding to use the indices... pushing onto a list though when it's getting large can involve re-writing pages though... so could be that - hard to tell. I'd suggest starting to get it to explain its query plan and see if that indicates anything obvious.

Comment: Not sure how to use `explain` method on `bulk_write` operation. Instead of that, I've queried a word and get it explained. You can check out the result above.

Comment: Thanks... I've not used mongo in a while - so not an expert - was just advising that info. should be in the Q itself because it'll hopefully help someone point out something if possible... good luck resolving it though.

Comment: The current query explain output you've included indicates `  'executionTimeMillis': 0` with only a single index & document lookup. Any room for improvement would be via reducing unnecessary overhead (for example, removing unused indexes) or looking for code or deployment bottlenecks. Can you provide more details on what you are measuring as slow -- is that the time for performing your bulk write operation? If so: how many documents are you inserting/updating, what sort of server resources do you have (RAM & disk in particular), and what is the total `dataSize` for your deployment?

Comment: I am trying to find unique words in approximately ~13M tweets. If we assume that on average a tweet contains 10 words, it means that about ~130M inserting/updating commands will be executed. In my last attempt, I've run the script for almost 16 hours straight, then I have to kill it. Because it processed like ~1M tweets. My computer has 28GB of ram and my hard disk is Hitachi HDS721010CLA332. The `dataSize` of whole `twitter` database is `{dataSize : 202887823327}` and you can find the real code I was running in the post.